# Stored procedure taking less time in local and taking more time in testing server

Tags: sql-server-2012, query-optimization

My stored procedure is running fast (2 sec) in local server with 25 million rows in the table, but on the testing server, it takes 15 seconds with only five million rows. How can I find out the reason? Is there any query to find the server and database properties of servers?

Comment: As the first step, compare the execution plans.

Comment: When running the queries (in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, presumably), turn on the "Actual Execution Plan". This will show you exactly what SQL Server does - compare those two to see where the differences are

Comment: ok.Thank you.whether we need to check any database or server property?